# Волосы его были нечёсаны

Tags: орфография, частица-не

*Волосы его были **нечесаны**, тонзура давно **небрита**, глаза горели неистовым огнем* (Б. Акунин).

***Небрит, нечёсан, неумыт*** ― всё это можно писать слитно?

В текстах встречаются **оба варианта**, например:

Был дядя лохмат, **небрит**, телогрейка на нём была надета прямо на голое тело (В. Астафьев).

Хожу **не стрижен и не брит**.  Вид у него далеко не презентабельный: **помят, грязен, не брит.**

А какое **правило у Розенталя** регулирует эти написания?

Answer (score 1):

> § 60. Частица не с причастиями
>
> 4. Пишется раздельно частица не с краткими формами причастия
> 5. Если причастие употребляется в значении прилагательного, то и при наличии пояснительных слов частица не пишется с причастием слитно
>
> http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=80

Как и в родственном вопросе, решение о возможности слитного написания может ограничиваться способностью конкретного причастия выражать значение прилагательного. У Розенталя пример: *доклад не подготовлен*; ср. *дверь не заперта* (= её не заперли) - в контексте "двери" трудно себе представить иное, разве что отвязанную от реальности стихотворческую вольность (незрим его бушприт, и трюма дверь колышется, незаперта в ночи...).

Comment: Alex_ander, эти правила я читала. В п. 5 приведены примеры с краткими формами, но они относятся к ПАРНЫМ отпричастным прилагательным. Эти прилагательные утратили значение действия и приобрели качественное значение, при этом они составляют пару с причастием, их написание можно вычислить по определенным признакам. А здесь что, полный авторский беспредел, нерегулируемая область письма? В одинаковых ситуациях встречаются обе формы. Значит, я могу писать так: пол не крашен/некрашен, брюки не глажены/неглажены. А как насчет приставочных форм? Пол непокрашен?

Comment: Думаю, что "небрит", "нечёсан" и "неумыт" _нужно_ писать слитно в подавляющем большинстве контекстов, где акцент - на наблюдаемом качестве (обросший, лохматый и грязный). "Хожу не брит" - только если недавно отказали в парикмахерской (печаль пришедшего побриться от несостоявшегося действия). В последнем примере небритость выглядит ошибкой.

Comment: P. S. К корректорам Акунина тоже есть вопрос относительно "давно небрит" - здесь не просто зависимое слово, а прямая ссылка на действие (умозаключение "он давно не брился" естественнее предположения "он давно ходит небритым"). Прецедент раздельного написания выражения " давно не брит" можно найти у Горького в "Самгине".